# Copy blob data from one table to another on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, copy, blob

I need to copy a set of data from one table to another that includes a `BLOB` column. I'm using an `INSERT` query with a subquery `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table(field1, field2, field3, blobfield, field4) 
    (SELECT t.myfield1, t.myfield2, t.id, t.blobfield, 'SomeConstant' 
        FROM tablename t)
```

All fields get copied correct, except the `BLOB`. I know I'm missing something, but I have no idea on how to make this work. Search did not help me. Anyone know how to solve it?

I'd prefer a solution in pure SQL, but I can use Ruby too.

Comment: +1 I was about to ask how to copy from one table to another until I found this related question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After playing a bit here, I found the error: the original column is a `MEDIUMBLOB`, not a `BLOB`. It works fine when I just correct the type. Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: No question is dumb question! Its matter of Ignorance.

Comment: Don't sorry, it helps me a lot. Thanks!.